# Do you get to use the poker table in the port observatory?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Aboard the Normandy in the Port Observatory there is a Poker Table, do you get the chance to use it? For example by playing with engineers Donelly and Daniels like in ME2.

Or is it only for decoration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaiden and James use it at one point for a game(not sure if who substitutes if Kaiden is dead), but in my play throughs Shepard never joins in.